# Making foreign keys with columns that are not primary keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I have observed some weird behavior in MariaDB, which I don't get:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INT);

CREATE foo1 (
  id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES foo(id));

-- doesn't compile

CREATE foo2 (
  id INT REFERENCES foo(id));

-- compiles, but foo2(id) isn't a foreign key
```

I wanted to use a table to restrict a column to a set of values, but it doesn't seem to work out, like I wanted it to...

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. Edit your question until you explain yourself. "doesn't compile" means nothing. "compiles but" means nothing. "foo2(id) isn't a foreign key" means nothing. (Also maybe you meant to write "primary" key.) "like I wanted it to" means nothing. "..." means nothing. Read & act on [mcve].  Read the manual about declaring PKs & FKs & everything else it says about them. Google your error message with & without your specific names. Google my comments re googling questions. PS PKs, CKs & FKs involve *sets* of columns.

Comment: Read the error message -- It is complaining at `foo1`.  Now, go check the syntax for `CREATE TABLE` and see what needs to be right there.  It is not about FKs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following observations:

- `CREATE foo1 ...` and `CREATE foo2 ...`, it's not a valid syntax. See
  [CREATE TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/).
- MariaDB accepts the `REFERENCES` clause in `ALTER TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements, but that syntax does nothing. MariaDB simply parses it without returning any error or warning, for compatibility with other DBMS's. See [Foreign Keys](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/).
- The referenced columns must be a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index. See [Foreign Keys](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/).